# New answers message while reading a question

Tags: feature-request, answers

A couple of times now, I've experienced that while reading a somewhat short - yet easy, understandable and valid - question, being answered three or more times before I'm done reading the question.

Now I'm ready to type my answer, but even though I started typing, I don't get any notifications about new answers. I suspect this is because the answers were submitted before I started typing my own.

After submitting my answer, I see three other answers I could have sworn was copied from what I just wrote - and the three others might think the same thing about me.

I'd like to suggest that the 'New answers' notification pops up even though, I haven't started writing an answer.

This would help me not making redundant answers (redundant as in writing exactly what someone else just did) and it could potentially help making a an answered question more clear and transparent.

Comment: I thought it does this already, but I may very well be wrong. +1 - this is the way is should be

Comment: @Pekka'sOrganicRepFarm - I *think* it only does that once you've typed something into the answer box and any answers added prior to you doing that don't trigger a notification which can be faintly annoying.

Comment: @Kev I don't know about the second part, but it does wait until you've started writing an answer before it starts checking

Comment: I think it also provides benefit to people here in read-only capacity -- they always get the "most up to date" version of the page too.

Comment: I've only ever had it pop up when I put something in the answer box.  Sometimes if I am reading a question I think I will answer, I'll put a few characters in there just to get a heads up that someone else is answering so I don't waste my time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature has been implemented.